# DLOOKUP from a query on current recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to do a dlookup where the criteria should be the current recordset and the textbox number (eg text13) should update to the next textbox number (eg text14):

```
'Count MasterList Items
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCount As Integer
Dim queryNameOrSQL As String
queryNameOrSQL = "qryMasterList"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(queryNameOrSQL)
rsCount = rs.RecordCount

i = 1
textBoxIndex = 13

    Do While i <= rsCount
        Me.Text & textBoxIndex = DLookup("[Item]", "MasterList", "WHERE RECORDSET = " & i)
        i = i + 1
        textBoxIndex = textBoxIndex + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: What problems are you having with that code?

Comment: I notice that you've done `rs.RecordCount` before using `rs.MoveLast`... perhaps Access hasn't counted all your records yet (I'm guessing, because as @HansUp says you've not really said what the issue is). See http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html (item 4) for the potential issue I've speculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to count the records - just loop along:

```
Const textBoxIndex As Long = 12
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim queryNameOrSQL As String
Dim recorditem As Long
queryNameOrSQL = "qryMasterList"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(queryNameOrSQL)

While Not rs.EOF
    recorditem = recorditem + 1
    Me("Text" & CStr(textBoxIndex + recorditem) & "").Value = DLookup("[Item]", "MasterList", "WHERE RECORDSET = " & recorditem & "")
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
```